# Does multiple looping affect response.json()?

Tags: python, json

As a part of a small project of mine, I'm using the requests module to make an API call. Here's the snippet:

```
date = str(day) + '-' + str(month) + '-' + str(year)
req = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id=" + str(distid) + "&date=" + date
response = requests.get(req,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
st = str(jprint(response.json()))
file  = open("data.json",'w')
file.write(st)
file.close()
```

The jprint function is as follows:

```
def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj,sort_keys=True,indent=4)
    return text
```

This is a part of a nested loop. On the first few runs, it worked successfully but after that it gave the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vax_alert2.py", line 99, in <module>
st = str(jprint(response.json()))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried adding a sleep of 1 second but got the same error. How should I resolve it?
Also, I checked it without using the jprint function yet got the exact same error.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think the error message is telling you about the received JSON data? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest recording the response in case of exception parsing the response as the response body is likely empty with an error status.  It's likely that you're getting a 403 or some other error status (potentially from a DDOS aware firewall).  Once you know the potentially errant (empty) response status, you may detect said status and throttle your requests accordingly.

```
try:
    st = str(jprint(response.json()))
    file  = open("data.json",'w')
    file.write(st)
    file.close()
except:
    print(response)
```

See the following (from https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/):

> In case the JSON decoding fails, r.json() raises an exception. For
> example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response
> contains invalid JSON, attempting r.json() raises
> simplejson.JSONDecodeError if simplejson is installed or raises
> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded on Python 2 or
> json.JSONDecodeError on Python 3.
>
> It should be noted that the success of the call to r.json() does not
> indicate the success of the response. Some servers may return a JSON
> object in a failed response (e.g. error details with HTTP 500). Such
> JSON will be decoded and returned. To check that a request is
> successful, use r.raise_for_status() or check r.status_code is what
> you expect.

Comment: I did that and I am getting 403 response. What should I do now?

Comment: If you goto the url you're requesting, you'll see that cloudfront is rejecting the request and why: 

"Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation."